# Scroll Area Added and Set Up but No Scrollbar Appears

Tags: c++, qt, qscrollarea

I've seen and tried various QT scrollArea solutions over the past 2 days but none of them work for me.  Here's my scroll area setup code as it stands in the MainWindow constructor.  This builds and runs without error but doesn't do anything.  The *scrollArea* and *ui->Contents* have already been set up in the form using QTcreator and the needed widgets have been moved into the scrollArea.

```
ui->scrollArea->installEventFilter(this);
ui->scrollArea->setMouseTracking(true);
ui->scrollArea->setWidget(ui->Contents);
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinimumSize);
ui->scrollArea->setLayout(layout);
```

The last line seems interchangeable with:

> layout->addWidget(ui->scrollArea)

but neither one changes the result, which is a fully-functioning application but without the scroll area I need.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the applicable form setup:]

Comment: What matters here is a size of an area to scroll and if vertical and horizontal scrollbars set to policy: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ScrollBarPolicy-enum https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#horizontalScrollBarPolicy-prop

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem which i solved by creating `scrollArea` and it's contents via code rather than form and only then using `setWidget()` method. I described the problem in  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56273866/incorrect-behaviour-of-scroll-bars-upon-zooming-an-image-in-qt).

In your case code should look something like this:

```
QScrollArea *scrollArea;

scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);    
scrollArea->installEventFilter(this);
scrollArea->setMouseTracking(true);
scrollArea->setWidget(Contents);//whatever Contents is, i recommend creating it via code
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinimumSize);
scrollArea->setLayout(layout);
```